# PHP socket_write isn't working

Tags: java, php, class, sockets, methods

I'm trying to send a simple message from a PHP script to a Java server, and everything connects to each other just fine until I try to use socket_write on PHP. If I try, the *entire* script stops working, things that should happen before socket_write too. Here's my code:

PHP:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = "localhost";
$port = 9999;


if(($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "Failed creating socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Socket created" . "\n";
}

if ($result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "\nFailed connecting to server: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Connected" . "\n";
}

$msg = "message"

socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));

?>
```

Java:

```
public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection;
    private static InputStream input;
    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server();
    }

    public static void Server() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(9999, 100);
                log("Socket created");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error creating ServerSocket: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            while(true) {
                try {
                    log("Waiting for connections...");
                    connection = server.accept();
                    log("Connection accepted");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Error creating connection: " + e.getMessage());
                }


                try {
                    log("Setting inputStream..");
                    input = connection.getInputStream();
                    log("Connections setup");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Error creating input stream: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                try {
                    if((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        log(message);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Error reading input: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }







    }

    public static void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

When socket_write is commented the page from the PHP script shows this:

```
Socket created

Connected
```

and the java log shows this:

```
Socket created
Waiting for connections...
Connection accepted
Setting inputStream..
Connections setup
Waiting for connections...
```

Which makes sense, because there is no message to be read so it waits for another connection.

But socket_write is uncommented, the Java Log shows "Waiting for connections" and the PHP page is blank, meaning it's not executing any of the script. So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a parenthesis at the end:

```
socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

Comment: I forgot in this code, not in the actual code. With it, it's still not working.

Comment: I guess you forgot the semi-colon at the end of `$msg = "message"` in this code too ?

Comment: I feel you bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Think. Now only i got the answer. Without "\n" new line socket_write is not send the data.

```
        $msg = "message \n";
```

You Should give new line.